# Have tmux default new-session to attach to named sessions

Tags: tmux

Id like have all new sessions attach to a named session if it already exists. I know the -A flag can accomplish this for me by doing

```
tmux new-session -A -s session-name
```

I tried adding these lines to my tmux.conf but am getting the error "Invalid option: new". Is there a way to set the default behavior for new sessions?

```
set -g new -A
OR
set -g new-session -A
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for here is a bash alias/function as opposed to adding something to your `.tmux.conf` since when you run `new-session` you are not actually *in* a tmux session yet. Try the following in your `.bashrc`

```bash
tmux() {
    if [[ "$1" == "new-session" ]] || [[ "$1" == "new" ]]; then
        command tmux "$@" -A
    else
        command tmux "$@"
    fi
}
```